# Export SQL table to CSV format with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I Try this solution to export from my database to CSV and it work but all Data are exported in one colones. I would like that compose me in The CSV like in the table data base. What is the problem in this code ?

```
<?php

// Database Connection

$host="localhost";
$uname="root";
$pass="";
$database = "a2zwebhelp"; 

$connection=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pass); 

echo mysql_error();

//or die("Database Connection Failed");
$selectdb=mysql_select_db($database) or 
die("Database could not be selected"); 
$result=mysql_select_db($database)
or die("database cannot be selected <br>");

// Fetch Record from Database

$output = "";
$table = ""; // Enter Your Table Name 
$sql = mysql_query("select * from $table");
$columns_total = mysql_num_fields($sql);

// Get The Field Name

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$heading = mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
$output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";

// Get Records from the table

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
}
$output .="\n";
}

// Download the file

$filename = "myFile.csv";
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

echo $output;
exit;

?>
```

Comment: instead of `\n` use the constant `PHP_EOL`

Comment: ... which is the same on UNIX and doesn't solve OPs problem if he's transfering from Unix to Windows ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "`\n`" as a line separator and open that file in i.e. notepad.exe, this will not be properly recognized as "carriage return linefeed" and the entire file *seems* to be just "one big line" - but actually it isn't!

You may terminate lines with "`\r\n`" to prevent this effect.

In order to have this automatically recognized by i.e. Excel, use `;` as field separator instead of `,`.